# Cannot successfully ping remote Ubuntu server from local PC?

Tags: networking, server

So I have 2 remote Ubuntu servers (S1 and S2), one of which I can ping (S1).  Also, I can connect to S2 by noVNC. I have a python server running in the default port on S2, but when I try to type the IP or subdomain, it shows that the connection timed out from my Windows PC. How can I fix this issue?

One method I tried diagnosing was using "test-netconnection [ip or subdomain]" on PowerShell for S2, and I received a timed out status. In addition, I tested both scenarios where the firewall was enabled, ensured all necessary ports should be allowed with ufw, as well as completely disabling firewall.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem for my case. The software, when ran without a container, blocked connections from going in and out regardless of the firewall status.  Therefore this question is resolved.